# python jpeg2000 compression with glymur

Tags: python, jpeg2000

anyone familiar with glymur module?

I would like to use this module to generate different jp2k type distortion images, but i really cant figure out how to apply this module, i found the code official page of glymur,

https://glymur.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.7.3/how_do_i.html#read-images

but it seems raised errors.

Can anyone show me a part of code which read a jp2 file from say, "D:/1.jp2", and saves this to "D:/2.jp2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the latest releases:

```
>>> glymur.version.version
'0.8.0'
>>> glymur.version.openjpeg_version
'2.1.0'
```

(the latter installed with macports on my Macbook Air, OSX 10.9.5) I copied the `nemo` image to the input filename you desire (not on `D:` of course as I don't have that on my Mac:-)...:

```
$ cp /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/glymur/data/nemo.jp2 ./1.jp2
```

then reading and writing is really simple:

```
>>> jp2 = glymur.Jp2k('1.jp2')
>>> oth = glymur.Jp2k('2.jp2', jp2[:])
```

and did verify (by eyeball with Preview) that the images look the same.

I suspect your problem may come from some wrong step on your installation (I had no problem with `sudo port install openjpeg` and then `sudo pip install glymur`, but I don't know what the equivalent steps are for Windows) -- or maybe 0.7.3 or whatever openjpeg release you're using have problems on Windows, I would't know about that.  Maybe try installing the latest and greatest releases...?

Comment: Thank you very much, i tried the version commend and it showed like>>> glymur.version.version
'0.8.0'
>>> glymur.version.openjpeg_version
'0.0.0'

Comment: @HeLiu, that all-zeroes version number for openjpeg is worrisome -- have you followed glymur's detailed installation instructions wrt openjpeg &c...?

Comment: you are right, my openjpeg was not installed properly, and now it's fixed. Thank you very much!